# i am integrating grapes.js in react js and facing problem in adding custom block component

Tags: reactjs

i am integrating grapes.js in react js, i wanted to add a custom block(Signature) and whenever i drag and drop that custom block on canvas i wanted to apply the react component (JSX) logic e.g whenever i drag and drop that custom block on canvas, a modal should be open same as provided by default build-in image block by grapes.js and when modal is open i wanted to apply digital Signature logic same as shown in pic below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDvtp.png)

Here is my code how i can do so and remeber my main point is to implement react component(JSX logic) to the block component:

````
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import grapesjs from "grapesjs";
import gjsBlockBasic from "grapesjs-blocks-basic";
import "grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { postThunk } from "../redux/GPPDSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setResponseV2 } from "../redux/layoutSlice";
import SocialModal from "../models/SocialModal";
import temp1 from "../assets/images/template1.jpg";

import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import { useRef } from "react";

// import { grapesjsReact } from "grapesjs-react";

function ProposalEditor() {
  // Hooks
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { user } = useSelector((State) => State.user);
  const {
    fetchedData: {
      data: { proposal },
    },
  } = useSelector((State) => State.GPPD);

  const [OTPModal, setOTPModal] = useState(false);
  const [edi, setEdi] = useState(null);
  const [runOnce, setRunOnce] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (runOnce) {
      const editor = grapesjs.init({
        container: "#gjs",
        width: "auto",

        // components: "<h1>Hello</h1>",

        // components: "<h1>Hello World Component!</h1>",
        fromElement: true,

        plugins: [gjsBlockBasic],

        pluginsOpts: {
          gjsBlockBasic: {},
        },
      });

      editor.DomComponents.addType("my-input-type", {
        model: {
          defaults: {
            tagName: "input",
          },
        },
        view: {
          render() {
            const { model, el } = this;
            const reactEl = React.createElement(
              ReactComponent,
              model.getAttributes()
              // TODO return children components as react elements
            );
            ReactDOM.render(reactEl, el);
            return this;
          },
        },
      });

      editor.BlockManager.add("my-input-type", {
        label: "my-input-type" || "input",

        id: "my-input-type",
        category: "Form",
        media: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22 9c0-.6-.5-1-1.3-1H3.4C2.5 8 2 8.4 2 9v6c0 .6.5 1 1.3 1h17.4c.8 0 1.3-.4 1.3-1V9zm-1 6H3V9h18v6z"></path><path d="M4 11.5h16v1H4z"></path></svg>`,
        content: {
          type: "button",
          content: '<button class="btn">Button</button>',
          style: {
            padding: "10px",
            border: "1px solid #ccc",
          },
        },
      });

      // Add some more blocks
      editor.BlockManager.add("my-button", {
        id: "my-button",
        label: "Button",
        category: "Form",
        media: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22 9c0-.6-.5-1-1.3-1H3.4C2.5 8 2 8.4 2 9v6c0 .6.5 1 1.3 1h17.4c.8 0 1.3-.4 1.3-1V9zm-1 6H3V9h18v6z"></path><path d="M4 11.5h16v1H4z"></path></svg>`,
        content: {
          type: "button",
          content: '<button class="btn">Button</button>',
          style: {
            padding: "10px",
            border: "1px solid #ccc",
          },
        },
      });
      editor.BlockManager.add("my-page-break", {
        id: "my-page-break",
        label: "Page Break",
        category: "Form",
        media: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M5 5h14v2h-2v10h2v2H5v-2h2V7H5z"/>
        <path d="M7 7h10v10H7z"/>
      </svg>
      `,
        content: {
          // type: "text",
          content:
            '<div class="page-break">----------------Page Break----------------</div>',
          style: {
            "text-align": "center",
          },
        },
      });
      editor.BlockManager.add("my-checkbox", {
        id: "my-checkbox",
        label: "Checkbox",
        category: "Form",
        media: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"/>
        <path d="M9 13l2 2 4-4"/>
      </svg>
      
      `,
        content: {
          type: "checkbox",
          content: '<input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" />',
        },
      });
      // editor.BlockManager.add("my-signature", {
      //   id: "my-signature",
      //   label: "Signature",
      //   category: "Form",
      //   media: `<svg
      //   viewBox="0 0 576 512"
      //   fill="currentColor"
      // >
      //   <path d="M64 0C28.7 0 0 28.7 0 64v384c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h256c35.3 0 64-28.7 64-64v-19.3c-2.7 1.1-5.4 2-8.2 2.7l-60.1 15c-3 .7-6 1.2-9 1.4-.9.1-1.8.2-2.7.2h-64c-6.1 0-11.6-3.4-14.3-8.8l-8.8-17.7c-1.7-3.4-5.1-5.5-8.8-5.5s-7.2 2.1-8.8 5.5l-8.8 17.7c-2.9 5.9-9.2 9.4-15.7 8.8s-12.1-5.1-13.9-11.3L144 381l-9.8 32.8c-6.1 20.3-24.8 34.2-46 34.2H80c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16s7.2-16 16-16h8.2c7.1 0 13.3-4.6 15.3-11.4l14.9-49.5c3.4-11.3 13.8-19.1 25.6-19.1s22.2 7.8 25.6 19.1l11.6 38.6c7.4-6.2 16.8-9.7 26.8-9.7 15.9 0 30.4 9 37.5 23.2l4.4 8.8h8.9c-3.1-8.8-3.7-18.4-1.4-27.8l15-60.1c2.8-11.3 8.6-21.5 16.8-29.7l94.8-94.8V160H256c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V0H64zm192 0v128h128L256 0zm293.8 139.7c-15.6-15.6-40.9-15.6-56.6 0l-29.4 29.4 71 71 29.4-29.4c15.6-15.6 15.6-40.9 0-56.6l-14.4-14.4zM311.9 321c-4.1 4.1-7 9.2-8.4 14.9l-15 60.1c-1.4 5.5.2 11.2 4.2 15.2s9.7 5.6 15.2 4.2l60.1-15c5.6-1.4 10.8-4.3 14.9-8.4l129.2-129.3-71-71L311.9 321z" />
      // </svg>

      // `,
      //   content: {
      //     // type: "checkbox",
      //     content: '<input type="text" class="my-checkbox" />',
      //   },
      // });

      // Load the page
      editor.setComponents(proposal?.proposalPage.pageHtmlData);
      editor.setStyle(proposal?.proposalPage.pageCssData);

      // Remove multiple blocks
      const blocksToRemove = ["link", "map", "column3-7"];
      blocksToRemove.forEach((blockId) => {
        editor.BlockManager.remove(blockId);
      });

      // Styling the convas
      const canvas = editor.Canvas.getElement();

      canvas.style.height = "90vh";
      canvas.style.width = "65%";
      canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red !important";
      canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
      canvas.style.margin = "30px 90px";

      // Add a save button to the editor
      const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
      console.log("AAAAAAAAAAA", saveButton);
      saveButton.textContent = "Save & Publish";
      saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const pageHtmlData = editor.getHtml();
        const pageCssData = editor.getCss();
        savePage(pageHtmlData, pageCssData, `/addProposal/${user?._id}`);
      });
      editor.Panels.addButton("options", {
        id: "save",
        className: "saveAndPublish",
        el: saveButton,
      });

      setEdi(editor);
    }
    setRunOnce(false);
  }, []);

  // Function to save the page data to the server
  const savePage = (pageHtmlData, pageCssData, api_url) => {
    dispatch(
      postThunk({
        proposalName: state?.proposalName,
        projectName: state?.projectName,
        proposalPage: { pageHtmlData, pageCssData },
        api_url,
      })
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (res?.payload?.data?.status == 200) {
          setOTPModal(true);
        } else if (res?.payload?.response.data != 200) {
          dispatch(setResponseV2(res.payload.response.data));
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Fornt end server crash", err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* <div class="panel__top">
        <div class="panel__basic-actions"></div>
      </div> */}
      <div id="gjs">
        <h1>Hello World Component!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
      </div>

      <SocialModal displayModal={OTPModal} setDisplayModal={setOTPModal} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default ProposalEditor;```


i try to apply custom block component and i am expecting drag and drop digital signature block
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).